# /dev/fedora/root does not exist, /dev/fedora/swap does not exist, /dev/mapper/fedora-root does not exist

Tags: fedora-26

I removed a preinstalled Windows 10 to install Fedora 26 on my Lenovo Yoga 9. Now, the computer doesn't boot. Gets stuck during the booting and 
[it shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFaej.jpg). Can Someone please tell me what I should do to fix this? I am completely new to Fedora. I indent to remove Windows 10 and keep Fedora 26.

Comment: This question is probably better on http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com/ because it is not about programming. That said, a little more detail will help. Did this happen the first time you booted after running the installation?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
After installation, the computer booted properly once or twice. And after that, it stopped booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this it. The problem was that while installing Fedora 26, I didn't do the partitioning properly. I left almost all of my hard drive space unpartitioned/free and had little to none for boot, swap etc.

So all I had to do was reinstall Fedora 26 with proper partitioning and the problem was solved. I mainly followed the following two links:

1. https://www.tecmint.com/fedora-25-installation-guide/
2. https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning.html

Proper partition is important!